Screenshot of the Week #124: Music and Dance!
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 124rth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Memor-X's screenshot from final-fantasy-xiv won with 14 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-09-16, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-09-23, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Music and Dance
This weeks theme is music and dance, as suggested by Elements in Space. Capture a moment with characters playing musical instruments and/or dancing.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Arrow to the Knee song - If anybody wants to see some true music and dance

Yeah yeah time flies ☺️

Hey Wipqozn, can you also accept the winning submission?

@pinckerman Done. Thanks for the reminder.

Hestu dancing with his buddies in zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom.


Honestly, not sure how anything is going to beat this one

maracas music intesifies

The Town Musicians of Bremen in the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine:


The Wiki page doesn’t really explain the musical nature of the group.  Are they an SATB vocal quartet?

@ElementsInSpace It's mostly the name that's on theme, to be fair. In the story they never really end up in Bremen or as musicians. But they are famous for being "musicians" nonetheless :)

Turtles all the way down... Wait a minute, that's not turtles

Basically this is from a quest where you enter a silly dream world with various stories like Brothers Grimm etc appearing, in that odd sense of Witcher humor shamelessly importing fiction from elsewhere into the in game universe (the Isle of Mists quest in the main campain is another hilarious example, subtly featuring Ciri as Snow White).


~ Beware - Deftones

deus-ex-mankind-divided


Rhiona and Squall in final-fantasy-8

I think that should be "Rinoa"?

Oh me and my broken brain

Another math-blaster one (sorry), but the theme provided the perfect opportunity to share this screenshot I got during a Disco Alert.

Btw I am using a camera movement changing mod I am working on, so I don't know if that disqualifies it.
Also I just realized none of the other screenshots of the week contain usernames in them...

Modded games are still games.

No need to apologize for posting screenshots from the same game repeatedly :)

true-lies


Although the game isn't exactly a good game per se, it's a nice SNES game for a little nostalgia trip... although it might be too difficult without cheating.

It looks like that angle happens at the very end of the dance before the fade out in the movie, although we don't see it at the same angle in the game and in the movie: https://youtu.be/WAxm-I-kzLA?t=50 And if you're curious, the music is Por Una Cabeza
